# transparent infowindow google maps apis

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, css

I can add a div into the infowindow content and set it's style giving it background color,  but I failed to make it transparent.

Is there a way to make the infowindow of google maps API transparent, without using other objects or 3rd party developed library?

Comment: Did you try the solution posted in this answer? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25278557/1193155

Comment: No, it does seem promising though. Its not discussing transparency and looks difficult, but I will give it a try. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with infowindow for a while with no luck to make it transparent. I finally resorted to using infobox (triggered by toms link in his comment).

For those interested I like to share my personal findings: it’s too hard to style infowindow that it was easier to change my application to use infobox. It can basically act very similar to infowindow and can be easily styled including having an opacity for transparency. I also hosted (infobox.js - close.gif - tipbox.gif) on my server giving full control over how it looks. So dont waste time with infowindow opacity.

I used the following code (taken from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jEhJ3/597/)) where I am setting opacity to 0.9:

```js
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
boxText.innerHTML = "Editing Locations ";

var myOptions = {
    content: boxText
            , disableAutoPan: false
            , maxWidth: 0
            , pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 80)
            , zIndex: null
            , boxStyle: {
                background: "url('images/tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
              , opacity: 0.90
              , width: "280px"
            }
            , closeBoxMargin: "2px 2px 2px 2px"
            , closeBoxURL: "images/close.gif"
            , infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            , isHidden: false
            , pane: "floatPane"
            , enableEventPropagation: false
};

var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
ib.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution - don't forget that you can mark your own answer as the correct answer